# Featured Question count is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bountied-tab, question-count

The number of featured questions here on meta is shown as 3 for me now, but when I click on the "Featured" tab I only see two questions.

[Only 2 questions http://img403.imageshack.us/img403/6278/featureda.png](http://img403.imageshack.us/img403/6278/featureda.png)

As far as I can tell I'm not hiding any questions, no greasmonkey scripts changing things.  I am only seeing the problem on meta.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I [posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38499/i-think-my-bounty-is-bugged-i-want-a-rebate/38502#38502) in Evan Carroll's question, the reason is that the third bounty question is voted too low to be shown on any of the front page views.

Comment: The mentioned question has now been deleted.