# Featured Questions count after filtering by tag in SO is not right

Tags: support, tag-search, bountied-tab

After filtering by [pdf] in SO I got a featured questions count of 2, however only one question is actually shown.

[image: Screenshot]

I saw [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38500/featured-question-count-is-incorrect) in meta.so but I am not sure if it also applies for this case, and one of the links in the accepted answer is currently dead.

Comment: Protip:  Crop your images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see both questions right now. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878538/cannot-create-pdf-document-with-400-pages-on-ios) is the second question with a bounty. It has the following tags:

[objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c)[ios](/questions/tagged/ios)[quartz](/questions/tagged/quartz)[pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf)[pdf-generation](/questions/tagged/pdf-generation)

As the counter on the right indicates that there are 2, that means it is returning 2 in your case. The reason you're only seeing one is because at least one of the 3 non-pdf tags on the question (the only tags not shared between the two questions) is on your Ignored Tags preferences, and you have ignored tags set to hidden.

Comment: I see. Questions on my ignored tags list were usually shown faded, so I did not expected any question to dissapear. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

The other question must have tags your in your ignored list.  Both questions show up for me until I add an ignored tag that exist on one of the questions.